# Saving int with sharedPreferenses when click on back

Tags: java, android

i'm (trying) to create a soccer goals calculator, with two activities, MainActivity and Score, but i'd like to save int value that represent goals when clicking on back button, that what i tried:

```
public class Score extends Activity {
public Button plus;
public Button minus;
public TextView scoretext;
public int value;
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public void save(View v){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("inte", value); // Storing integer
    editor.apply(); // commit changes
}
public void restore(View v){
    this.sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myPerf",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (this.sharedpreferences.contains("inte")) {
        okeh.setText(this.sharedpreferences.getInt("inte",value));
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
    plus = this.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    scoretext=this.findViewById(R.id.scoretext);
    minus=this.findViewById(R.id.minus);

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value++;
            String scorestring=String.valueOf(value);
            scoretext.setText(scorestring);
        }
    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value--;
            String scorestring=String.valueOf(value);
            scoretext.setText(scorestring);
        }
    });
    sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains("inte")) {
        okeh.setText(sharedpreferences.getInt("inte", value));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are the parameters for your methods save and restore a View ?

Comment: Still not working?

Answer (score 1):

You have to Override the **onBackPressed** method in your Score activity and save the int **score** in the shared preferences.

When you press the device back button the **onBackPressed** method will be called automatically and your latest Score will be saved in the shared preferences.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("inte", value); // Storing integer
    editor.apply(); // commit changes

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: And what will happen if user switches to another application and Android removes it from memory?

Comment: Then you can also override the **onUserLeaveHint** method as well and call onBackPressed in that function like this

   @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        onBackPressed();
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }

Comment: but how to settext when reopening the acitivity?

Comment: call restore method in onResume of your activity like this.

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      
        SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (this.sharedPreferences.contains("inte")) {
            okeh.setText(this.sharedPreferences.getInt("inte", value) + "");
        }


        super.onResume();

    }

Answer (score 1):

Your save and restore methods have a parameter `View v` and i'm not sure why.

**Change it to an integer**

```
public void save(int value){
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("inte", value); // Storing integer
    editor.apply(); // commit changes
}

public int restore(){
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (this.sharedPreferences.contains("inte")) {
        okeh.setText(this.sharedPreferences.getInt("inte",value));
    }
    return sharedPreferences.getInt("inte", 0); //return 0 if no data found
}
```

**Alt + Insert and select override method**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Put your sharedpreferences here that saves the int.
    save(value);
}
```

And now you can call your `save method` on places where you want to save the int value.

EDIT

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value++;
            String scorestring=String.valueOf(value);
            scoretext.setText(scorestring);
            save(value);
        }
    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value--;
            String scorestring=String.valueOf(value);
            scoretext.setText(scorestring);
            save(value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: a button for save and one for restore

Comment: @Planetofshadows where do you call these methods? I rewrote them so now it accepts an int value and you can call save in onBackPressed(); so that it saves the int value.

Comment: that did'nt work for me, when i click on back then i enter the score activity the score is 0

Comment: @Planetofshadows well that means your variable value is still 0

Comment: @Planetofshadows i changed your restore method so now it returns an int value, check my edit.

Comment: In onCreate write value = restore();

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have an error at the restore it say i need return

Comment: i have some other errors, the score actvity is completly white, do you have discord please? and thanks again

Comment: @Planetofshadows no i don't but if you have github or make one you can upload your project so i can take a look myself.

Comment: @Planetofshadows I already found my mistake, check the restore method i edited it.

Comment: i uploaded it, please give me your email so i can send you the link

Comment: please i really need help

Comment: @Planetofshadows just post it here the link

Comment: hi, sorry for the late comment, but i switched to unity, it's better^^ android studio sucks. thanks for your answer anyway.